# value into dictionary with array data - swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am really not getting this - why is this not working?

```
var listOfFruit = ["Apple", "Banana","Lemon"]
var emptyDict = [String: String]()
var key = ["Name of Fruit","Name of Fruit","Name of Fruit"]

func createDictionary(){
    var index: Int
    index = listOfFruit.count

    for index in listOfFruit {
        emptyDict = [key[index]:listOfFruit[index]]
        print (emptyDict)
    }
}
```

I am getting the usual :

Comment: What were you trying to do?

Comment: Can you type in text what kind of result you're trying to get? Perhaps that's more clear.

Comment: The problem there is every time it loops you assign a new dictionary instead of a new key/value to emptyDict

Comment: Even if he does things right, he'll end up with a dictionary with 1 key since the values of `key` are all the same.

Comment: pelase see below comment for further explanation. Thank you Leo for your comment - you are right - I am actually creating a new dictionary with every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm trying to guess what you need because your question is pretty unclear.*

**IF** given this input

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana","Lemon"]
var keys = ["Name of Fruit", "Name of Fruit", "Name of Fruit"]
```

you want this output

```
["Name of Fruit 2": "Lemon", "Name of Fruit 0": "Apple", "Name of Fruit 1": "Banana"]
```

Then you can use this code

```
let dict = zip(fruits, keys).enumerate().reduce([String:String]()) { (var result, elm) -> [String:String] in
    let key = "\(elm.element.1) \(elm.index)"
    let value = elm.element.0
    result[key] = value
    return result
}
```

or this code

```
assert(keys.count == fruits.count)
var dict = [String:String]()
for i in 0..<fruits.count {
    let key = "\(keys[i]) \(i)"
    let value = fruits[i]
    dict[key] = value
}
```

Comment: thank you for that - it works great, even though that I don't understand the code at all - too complex for me!! all I want to do is to fill the dictionary with data. So, I have all the values and all the keys in separate arrays and I want to load these two arrays into the dictionary.

Comment: @kangarooChris: I added to my answer an easier block of code, please take a look at it.